# Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted

Tags: android-studio

I tried to install **android studio** after installing **Java SE 9** version an get this error
[image]

Comment: My issue was specifically a freak issue with build-tools 33.0.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992/332578

Answer (score 41):

Files -> setting -> Android SDK -> you can see the 'edit' that you can change the path of the Android SDK. ->  click the download button

Comment: I didn't have a "download" button, but clicking "next" in the wizard view worked for me.

Comment: Very odd, the regular SDK manager flow was just looping giving the above error. Follow these steps and it magically works. I think stuff was a little confused due to a recent Windows reset install.

Answer (score 20):

1. File > Setting > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > [Edit] Button Click (Blue Color Link Button)
2. then, it will be show a Dialog [ SDK Setup ]
3. push [Next] button & [Finish] button

Good Luck ~~ ♪♬  (^.^)

Answer (score 4):

> To change the update channel for an existing install, proceed as follows:
>
> 1. Open the **Preferences** window by clicking **File** > **Settings** (on Mac, **Android Studio** > **Preferences**).
> 2. In the left panel, click **Appearance & Behavior** > **System Settings** > **Updates**.
> 3. Be sure that **Automatically check for updates** is checked, then select a channel from the drop-down list (see figure).
> 4. Click **Apply** or **OK**.

[image]

It's from [**Android Developers Guidelines**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)

Answer (score -4):

You can go to you sdk manager and download the lastest API for sdk platform, all of sdk tools and check for SDK Update Sites

Comment: describe the way, please