# Android Studio 4.2.2 - Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-build-tools

I have a fresh install of the software, and whenever I try to run the build, it fails, giving me this error message.

Troubleshooting: I've already tried to uncheck 31.0.0 version in the SDK manager, and put in older stable versions, but every time I try to run it, it starts installing 31.0.0 again.

Comment: I have this problem too. I tried to delete the build-tools version in the sdk directory, and then reinstall, but I get the same error. Have you been able to fix the issue yet?

Answer (score 3):

No need to downgrade. Renaming `d8.jar` & `d8.bat` to `dx.jar` and `dx.bat` respectively worked for me
as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992/7450780)

Answer (score 1):

Work for me

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Change Build Tools Version from 31.0.0 to 30.0.3

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with version 31.0.0.

Using the SDK tools section, click 'Show Package Details', uncheck 31.0.0 and check 30.0.3. Press apply.

This then uninstalls 31.0.0 and installs version 30.0.3. You should be able to apply those changes and then just change the `buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"` in your app gradle file to `buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"`.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change the

> buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

to

> buildToolsVersion "the-build-tool-version"

in all of your gradle files