# Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, android-sdk-build-tools

Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

Studio Version 4.2.1

Tried Reinstalling and removing previous versions
Tried adding dx.jar and dx.bat from build-tools-30.0.3 (This is not a good solution even after adding it shows dx.jar file is not there)

Comment: Let's not open questions on the exact same topic just because the answer doesn't work for you. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68396658/android-installed-build-tools-version-31-0-0-is-corrupted#comment120879461_68396658 which was already a duplicate

Comment: Please see the timestamp of the questions

Comment: see answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted

Comment: Yeah thanks @zuraff I know that it will work when downgraded to 30.0.3/30.0.2 but I am asking about 31

Answer (score 31):

The main problem is the two files missing in SDK build tool 31 that are

dx.bat
dx.jar
The solution is that these files are named d8 in the file location so changing their name to dx will solve the error.

The steps are below.

For Windows
go to the location

```
 "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0"
find a file named d8.bat. This is a Windows batch file.

rename d8.bat to dx.bat.

in the folder lib ("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0\lib")

rename d8.jar to dx.jar
```

Remember AppData is a hidden folder. Turn on hidden items to see the AppData folder.

For macOS or Linux

```
# change below to your Android SDK path
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0 \
  && mv d8 dx \
  && cd lib  \
  && mv d8.jar dx.jar
```

Now you can run the project

Comment: thanks, you saved the day.

Comment: there are two files in /33.0.0/d8 and /33.0.0/lib/d8 change them to /33.0.0/dx and /33.0.0/lib/dx

Comment: Thanks. It also works for build tools 34.0.0

Answer (score 14):

As pointed out in other issues, the problem is that dx (or dx.bat) is no longer available. This was a purposeful change [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-switching-to-d8-dexer.html) in 2018.

Suggested resolutions of renaming d8 to dx or copying it from build tools 30.0.0 *will* resolve the issue, but dx isn't likely to return. So you'll be stuck patching every build tools installation on every developer's machine going forward.

The more forward-compatible solution is to upgrade your Android gradle plugin. This isn't as straightforward as just changing the number in gradle, but I find that Android Studio's upgrade process works well for my projects. If you open your project-level `build.gradle` file, open up the quick fixes menu from the lightbulb over your

```
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:...'
```

section. From here, choose to upgrade to the newest possible version (not just 4.x in my case).

[image: Quick fixes menu open. Option to "Invoke Upgrade Assistant for upgrade to 7.1.3" selected]

Then I run the upgrade steps for literally everything:
[image: Upgrade assistant window open with all items checked.]

My issue was Unity specific though: I needed to use the system Android SDK rather than the one built in, but Unity itself likes to regenerate these build files and will just grab the newest buildtools it can find. To reduce manual steps and to avoid having to export my project, I instead chose to generate my module-level `build.gradle` files from my "Player Settings>Publishing Settings" window:
[image: Publishing Setting section open with "Custom Main Gradle Template" and "Custom Launcher Gradle Template" open]

Both files will have a line that looks like:

```
buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'
```

Which you can replace with:

```
buildToolsVersion '30.0.0'
```

From Unity, this lets me build and deploy projects as I had before without modifying the `buildtools` installation.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android SDK Build Tools 31.0.0, instead of `dx` files, we have `d8` files. You can try to create a copy and rename it into `dx` files.

1. Create a copy of `d8.bat` and rename it to `dx.bat`.
2. In the `lib` folder, create a copy of `d8.jar` and rename it to `dx.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle` file. It should be same as which you have installed from `SDK Manager -> SDK Tools` where you will find `Android SDK Build-Tools 31`.

`dx` file will be available at the location of sdk `Android SDK dir\build-tools` and you will find `31.0.0-rc3 (Open this folder and check manually if dx file is there or not)`. If all works fine then restart and rebuild the project.

If `dx` file is not there then uninstall the build tools from Android Studio and reinstall it again from Android Studio.

Comment: This is a temp solution right. Normally we don't copy any files. So this might be an issue with 31.0.0

Answer (score -2):

Issue resolved For me by changing the version 31 to 30 in build.gradle in following tags
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

```
    targetSdkVersion 30
```