# Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager. Unable to run my project on my external device

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I was trying to connect an external device to run my project in Android Studio with my MacBook Air M1, but after so many tries I was unable to do anything when this error pops. I have also tried to reinstall it but nothing changes. Can somebody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio error "Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted)

Comment: Please search SO before posting new questions. This topic has been discussed a few times this week.