# How specify an Android SDK Build Tools version on Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm having a serious problem trying to create an Android CI/CD in Azure DevOps. Turns out the pipeline tries to use the latest version of BuildTools to build the apk, but the latest version (31.0.0) seems to be having problems.

I would like to force Azure to use version 30.0.3 that I have already tested is working perfectly.

Azure Log Using BuildTools 31.0.0

[image: Azure Log 31]

Local log using BuildTools 31.0.0

[image: Local Log 31]

Local log using BuildTools 30.0.0

[image: Local Log 30]

I'm using Ionic with cordova to generate my Android project, although [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-gradle-properties) says it supports cli arguments to force build tools version.

eg.: `ionic cordova run android -- --gradleArg=-P cdvBuildToolsVersion=30`

It still generates in a way that will always use the most current version installed in the cordovaLib module

build.gradle [app module]

```
// The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }

...

compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
```

build.gradle [cordovaLib module]

```
cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()

...

compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
```

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file? Do you have there defined `30.0.3` version?

Comment: Sorry @Krzysztof Madej , I forgot to tell you that I'm using Ionic and it ends up forcing a version of Cordova that always forces you to use the last installed version of Build Tools (I updated the issue) with findLatestInstalledBuildTools

Comment: I'm thinking of deleting this issue, as I realized that this is a limitation of Android/Cordova/Ionic, I believe the only way out is to make a temporary workarround with the one I mention here https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1288#issuecomment-887819881

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68437642/355364), the issue is that SDK 31+ isn't compatible with AGP under 7.x. How could you update AGP under Azure DevOps CI?

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary workaround that seems to make sense for this type of case and if someone has this type of problem in the future, it might be useful:

Just put a step in the pipeline to remove the corrupted build-tools, in this case, 31.0.0

```
- script: $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --uninstall 'build-tools;31.0.0'
  displayName: 'Workaround'
```

Comment: Batusta, What path you set for ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: it's an environment variable defined by Azure Dev Ops itself, in my case I'm using a MacOS machine so the ANDROID_HOME value was set to /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk