# Ionic Cordova Android: No usable Android build tools found. Highest 30.x installed version is 30.0.2; minimum version required is 30.0.3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have updated Cordova Android to the latest (10.1.1) and now when I build I get:

> No usable Android build tools found. Highest 30.x installed version is 30.0.2; minimum version required is 30.0.3

I have the following reported when I start the build:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

I also have the folder `C:\Users\peter\.android` an `C:\Users\peter\.gradle`

I upgraded Android Studio,dowloaded SDK's etc, and started a new project after reading elsewhere this may update the build tools. This did make a difference, as originally the error reported installed version was `29.0.2` and now it is 30.0.2, but something is looking for `30.0.3`.

The version `30.0.3` is coming from the file `platforms\android\cdv-gradle-config.json`, and I have the following folders in `C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools..

[image]

I cannot see how to get `30.0.3`, when I look at https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools#groovy I don't see this version

Why might this config have this version, or where I can get this version of the build tools?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Today, I could finally install version 30.0.3.

In Android Studio, I could see and install it from here...

[image]

After this, and then also having to remove the whitelist plugin (it is not required any more), I could get it to build.

Only hassle now is it outs to a `.aab` and not an `.apk` so side load testing now harder. But the main issue, the building is now working (on Windows PC).. Now hopefully can do the same on the Mac.

Comment: Incredible, saved my life! For the guys unable to find ```settings```, go to ```help``` > ```find action``` and type ```settings```.

Comment: Thank you! So hard to find everything in this tool.

Comment: Just so you know, specifying `packageType` as `apk` will generate an `apk`.

Comment: Incredible sir! Bravo for the detailed tutorial which shows how to reveal the package details. It's important because at first you will not see it.

Answer (score 19):

Possibly of use to people reading this--

This is answered in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1391).  In short, major version upgrades of the build tools are likely to break Cordova, so the latest Cordova only supports build tools version 30.0.3 .  The error message asking for "30.0.3 or higher" is misleading, and was an oversight and will be changed.  Currently, 30.0.3 is the only version that works here and that Android Studio will install from the "SDK Tools" tab.

Solution:  Install version 30.0.3, and it should work (it works for me).

Comment: How did you install specific version?

Comment: @katzmopolitan You have to check the 'Show Package Details' option in SDK Tools panel, then you will see the versions.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the android platform version. Run the code `ionic info` to find the version. If it is `10.1.1`, remove it by running the code `ionic cordova platform rm android` and install the version `8.0.0` by the command `cordova platform add android@8.0.0`. Run the build code.

Comment: install version 8 means only can support until Android 9, is it correct? [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

cvd-gardle-config.json

```
{
  "MIN_SDK_VERSION": 29,
  "SDK_VERSION": 32,
  "COMPILE_SDK_VERSION": null,
  "GRADLE_VERSION": "7.4.2",
  "MIN_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION": "29.0.2",
  "AGP_VERSION": "7.2.1",
  "KOTLIN_VERSION": "1.5.21",
  "ANDROIDX_APP_COMPAT_VERSION": "1.4.2",
  "ANDROIDX_WEBKIT_VERSION": "1.4.0",
  "ANDROIDX_CORE_SPLASHSCREEN_VERSION": "1.0.0-rc01",
  "GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.10",
  "IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED": false,
  "IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED": false
}
```

at MIN_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION  set your installed version at error you can see your installed version