# Ionic build time error "No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher"

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm stack on one error in on build time with Cordova.
I have already installed android build tools but ionic through error "No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher". I do not understand why this error show. Below mentioned error, please check and help me.

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\ionic\demoApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\ionic\demoApp\platforms\android\gradlew :app:bundleRelease -b C:\ionic\demoApp\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 3):

The error produced by Cordova is misleading (there is an open issue [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1391)).

Cordova by default is looking for build tools version >= 30.0.3 but still within version 30. The purpose for this behaviour is so Cordova doesn't automatically pick up a build tools version that it is likely not compatible with.

Using `<preference name="android-buildToolsVersion" value="32.0.0" />` should allow you to override this behaviour and Cordova will use the desired build tools version as requested.

However there are known incompatiblities with Build tools version 31, and I doubt build tools 32 will work either. I'd **highly suggest** installing build tools 30.0.3 as that's the version that is tested against the current version of cordova.

Comment: bro, you save lots of time for me. i wasted 3 hours stresful for this. all environment sett up correctly but still not detected, my sdk is ```32.0.0.```. this really unexpected behaviour to must set manually. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your android build tools directory

```
C:\foo\sdk\build-tools\32.0.0
```

and rename d8.bat to dx.bat

Now do the same for d8.jar in the /lib folder.

Credits go to 'user16475264' (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992/3365033)

Comment: Not working, same error found.

Comment: C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0 contains dx.bat and C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\lib contains dx.jar?

Comment: Yes, I have changed file name according to you. Also I have tried on ubuntu 18.04 but same error found.