# How to solve Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javac

I am trying to run Android project in an AVD Manager. When the program compiles it throws an   exception.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 32.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:160)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:128)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:163)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:133)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:147)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:45)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:55)....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Installed Build Tools revision 32.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:183)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:113)
    ... 137 more
```

I have tried several solutions for a workaround. I have tried to change CompledSDK, TargetSDK and BuildTools to 31, 30 and 29 but none of them worked for me.

Any help!

Comment: take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted) if you haven't already .

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following command inside your project directory:

> ./gradlew clean

and re-run it in the studio.