# React native build failed even after all things are good?

Tags: react-native, failed-installation

[image]* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Installed Build Tools revision 30.0.3 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 6s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio error "Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted)

Answer (score 1):

Can you look at your log, it  says the build tool version 30.0.3 is corrupted
and suggested removing and installing from the SDK manager.

you can follow below steps:

1. Open the SDK manager by clicking on the icon in the top right of
   Android Studio. (Or go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior >
   System Settings > Android SDK)
2. Open the SDK Tools tab
3. At the bottom-right, click "Show Package Details"
4. Find Android SDK Build-Tools and uncheck the checkbox next to 30.0.3
5. Click Apply in the bottom of the window. That will delete the
   component.
6. Now check the checkbox next to 30.0.3
7. Click Apply in the bottom of the window. That will reinstall it.